# Replacing tab characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, space

Please consider the following HTML <pre> element:

```
This is some  
example code which    
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;contains tabs
```

I would like to replace all of the tab characters with four non-breaking space characters in HTML (i.e. &nbsp;). I have tested the above pre element with JavaScript for the presence of tab characters as follows:

```
$('pre').ready(function() {
    alert(/\t/.test($(this).text()));
});
```

But it is always returned false. Can anyone tell me the correct process by which to replace tab spaces from the source code to HTML NBSPs? The tabs have been added by Komodo Edit, and are visible when viewing the source.

Answer (score 56):

You can do it like this:

```
$('pre').html(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
});
```

That will loop through all `pre` elements on the page and call the function for each of them. jQuery's [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function uses the return value of the function we give to replace the content of each element. We're using `String#replace` to replace all (note the `g` flag on the regexp) tab characters in the HTML string with four non-breaking spaces.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ifova4)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it was actually a problem with Komodo Edit not correctly inserting tab characters. I added tabs in Notepad and all works fine!

Comment: My God, it's full of stars!

Answer (score 12):

It removes line breaks, extra spaces and line breaks:

```
function removeNewlines(str) {
//remove line breaks from str
str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
str = str.replace(/\t/g, ' ');
str = str.toString().trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"");
console.log(str);
}
```

Demo:

```js
function removeNewlines(str) {
//remove line breaks from str
str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
str = str.replace(/\t/g, ' ');
str = str.toString().trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"");
  console.log(str);
}

$('#acceptString').click(function() {
    var str = prompt('enter string','');
    if(str)
        removeNewlines(str)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Enter String' id='acceptString' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var tab = RegExp("\\t", "g");
document.getElementById("text").value =
document.getElementById("text").value.replace(tab,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```