# converting apple-tab-space into &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, dom

is there a library that convert `apple-tab-space` into `&nbsp;` character ?

if there is none, can you please suggest an efficient way in doing so?

Im having some trouble with my code editor using contenteditble div (nevermind)

Comment: I haven' crossed `apple-tab-space`.  what is it?

Comment: (layman's term) a browser way of interpreting tab space

Comment: @fireflieslive Is this what you're looking for http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/06/apple-tab-span/ ?

Comment: What's a "tab space"? Do you just mean when you press `Tab` that `&nbsp;` should be inserted into the content editable field?

Comment: Can you add a code sample of what you've tried? It's still not clear what you mean by "apple-tab-space".

Answer (score 3):

Try listening to `keydown`, and appending `&nbsp;` to the `<input>`'s `val()`:

```
$(function () {
    $('textarea').keydown(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == '9') {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '&nbsb;')
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

#### Plnk here : http://plnkr.co/edit/GF80PSJPLiBOCPJINDuv?p=preview

The `return false;` is key (no pun) as hitting tab within an input will inherently advance the user to the next input. Worth noting that this *is* the expected behavior, so keep that in mind when presenting this functionality to users.

#### Update : non-jQuery example

It occurred to me that you didn't tag this question with jQuery, so here's the vanilla JavaScript solution as well:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == '9') {
            this.value = this.value + '&nbsb;';
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}, false);
```

#### Plnk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QJc3Lt2TQGBo8CQqtESO?p=preview

Comment: Last issue is that, i need a copied text with apple-tab-span to be converted also when i paste it in the contenteditable div

Comment: is there a hex value or similar for what `apple-tab-span` outputs? I think what you may be referring to is an "em-dash" or `&mdash;`, but maybe not. Can you include it in your answer or a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (replace "myDiv" with a selector for the actual div you're targeting):

```
$('#myDiv').html(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;');
});
```

I pulled this code snippet from this answer: [Replacing tab characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562756/replacing-tab-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds like when in your browser or code editor on your Mac you want to remap a key combination (command-tab) to output "&nbsp" (omitted semi-colon for display purposes). 
 If that is indeed what you want to do there is a great utility called keyremap4macbook that you can check out ***[here](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/)***. I use it for remapping keys during remote desktop sessions and it works really great. You can have mappings only take place for certain applications, which is even better than the generic key mapping utilities that are out there.