# Replace tabs and newline in html tags which start on some text

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I have some HTML output code, example part:

```
<div class="header">
  \n\t
  <div class="header-inner">
    \n\t\t
    <div class="title">
      Title\n\t\t
    </div>
    \n\t
  </div>
  \n
</div>
```

Div **.title** have newline and tabs before it close. It's possible delete it (replace with JS pattern)? Text random, not always **"Title"**, and tags with the same problem can be a lot.

Need:

```
<div class="header">
  \n\t
  <div class="header-inner">
    \n\t\t
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    \n\t
  </div>
  \n
</div>
```

Comment: You want to replace **all** tabs and newlines inside the div.title? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562756/replacing-tab-characters-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, in div.title and in all tags which start with text.

Comment: I need regexp for replace, but i don't know it's possible or not, html code return gulp pipe, and i can't use jQuery or native js.

Comment: Are you looking for just emty tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please review this one

```
var x = `<div class="header">\n\t<div class="header-inner">\n\t\t<div class="title">Title\n\t\t</div>\n\t</div>\n</div>`;
var y = x.replace(/(\w+[\s]?)\s[\s]+/gi,function(a, b) {return a.trim();});
console.log(x, y);
```

Comment: im glad it can help :)