# Remove the tab space or line breaks in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file and i am getting the json content which may contain new lines in it. Now i am facing a problem. I am getting the below error :

```
Unexpected token ↵ in JSON at position 9
```

Note: the error message says specificaly this symbol: '↵'. What does this mean?

My JSON:

```
{"T":". 
^00:00:43^2008-09-11 12:00:00.0"}
```

But if i remove the new line (not sure if its a new line or a tab space no matter what i am facing this issue even if its a tab space or new line. It works fine with normal space.). Below is the modified JSON and it looks good.

Modified JSON:

```
 {"T":".^00:00:43^2008-09-11 12:00:00.0"}
```

I have tried to follow similar threads like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562756/replacing-tab-characters-in-javascript) and some similar threads. but nothing works even after applying those. Any help is appreciated here please.

This is one the solution i have tried:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Is there anyway to detect these linebreaks and tab spaces and remove them?

Comment: About the `↵`, it's a symbol used to visualize a newline.

Comment: @PredatorIWD so in this case its teh new line which is causing the problem in the jsonstring?

Comment: What does `yourString.charCodeAt(9)` show?

Comment: I believe in the above JSon 8th char is space and 9th is a new line here..I tried to replace new lines with normal space but thats not working either. @Barmar. So just trying to take suggestions here

Comment: If it's a newline then the solutions in the other questions should work. That's why I wanted to see the code, maybe it's some other special character.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the result of `.replace()` back into the variable? It doesn't modify the string in place.

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we're just guessing at what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Did you just replace `\n`?  You may also have to replace carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: Hi @Barmar. This is one the solution i have tried:                                      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");    and similarly other replace()'s.

Comment: Never-mind that comment I deleted. I was thinking of `parse`, not `stringify`.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be calling `JSON.stringify()`. That will convert the newlines in the string to literal `\n`, which won't be matched by the escape sequences in the regexp. Just do the replacement directly on the bad data.

```js
var data = `{"T":". 
^00:00:43^2008-09-11 12:00:00.0"}`;
var jsonString = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"");
var object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: i have the above suggestion. But still it says the same message. Not sure why is it showing even if we have removed new line char's :(

Comment: I am getting the result as a AJAX call. Do you think that is the reason its not working in that case? @Barmar

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference. A newline is a newline.

Comment: zach mentioned this in his comment : "Not on browser Javascript side. Formatting has to be done before it reaches browser Javascript." for my question : is there a way to detect new line chars and replace them in ajax call.

Comment: That's not true. It only has to be fixed before calling `JSON.parse()`. There's nothing wrong with returning newlines in the response text.

Comment: Make sure you're not using `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` call. You need to get the text so you can fix it before trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var jsonString = data.replace(/[\n\r\t]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON value. 
If you refer to https://www.json.org/,
newline, carriage returns and etc will need to be included in the value itself.

There is no  way to modify because the parser already throws the error.

The only solution I can think of is for the author of the JSON file to amend their value like your Modified JSON or if they want to preserve that newline,

```
{"T":".\n^00:00:43^2008-09-11 12:00:00.0"}
```

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to detect new line chars and replace them with \n? @zack

Comment: Not on browser Javascript side. Formatting has to be done before it reaches browser Javascript.

Comment: so there is no way to check for new line chars from the ajax call response? :O not sure what should be the solutions here :(

Comment: Or you can read the file with Ajax and treat the response data as a regular text/plain mime type first. From there, you can do those parsing and cleaning as mentioned by other answers. Then do JSON.parse().

Comment: Hi Barmar, sorry I dont have reputation to comment in your answer. In your code snippet, you added the ` quote which OP's value doesn't contain that back quote. I assume he fetch the JSON file as it is. My earlier comment is in agreement with your explanation; Treat as regular text/plain first and do the parsing on the string, then parse to JS object.